# React component doesn't refresh

Tags: reactjs

I am having an issue where my page doesn't refresh when I call the refresh function I passed.

```js
function ProductsPage(props) {
    const [products, setProduct] = useState([])
    const [shouldRefresh, setRefresh] = useState(false)

    function refreshProducts() {
        setRefresh(!shouldRefresh)
    }

    const token = localStorage.getItem("token")
    const headers = { Authorization: "Token " + token }

    useMemo(() => (axios.get("/products", { headers: headers }).then((resp) => (
        setProduct(resp.data)
    ))
    ), shouldRefresh)

    return (
        <Box className="cardDeck">
            <Redirect_if_not_logged_in />
            {products.map((product) => (
                <InfoCard product={product} refresh={refreshProducts}></InfoCard>
            )).reverse()}
        </Box>
    )
}
```

Whenever I call `props.refresh()` from the InfoCard, nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use useEffect hook instead of useMemo

```
function ProductsPage(props) {
  const [products, setProduct] = useState([]);
  const [shouldRefresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);

  function refreshProducts() {
    setRefresh(!shouldRefresh);
  }

  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const headers = {
    Authorization: "Token " + token,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("/products", {
        headers: headers,
      })
      .then((resp) => setProduct(resp.data));
  }, [shouldRefresh]);

  return (
    <Box className="cardDeck">
      <Redirect_if_not_logged_in />
      {products
        .map((product) => (
          <InfoCard product={product} refresh={refreshProducts}></InfoCard>
        ))
        .reverse()}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The shouldRefresh in useMemo, should be in a dependancy array like this:

```
useMemo(() => (axios.get("/products", { headers: headers }).then((resp) => (
    setProduct(resp.data)
))
), [shouldRefresh])
```

Also I don`t think you need useMemo here, useEffect would do the same thing